# How to avoid duplicate submission for single input forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a single input form:

```
<form id="my_form">
  <input id="my_input" type="text" />
</form>
```

In most browsers, when a user types text in this single input and hits 'enter' the form is submitted. That's great but I want to go one step further and make it so that if the user types something and focus is lost, the form is submitted.

I've currently tapped into jQuery's `change` event like so:

```
$("my_input").change(function() {
  $("my_form").submit();
});
```

This works for the case when I change the input value and focus out but if I change the input value and hit 'enter' then the form is submitted twice (once for 'enter' and once for `change`).

I was starting to go down the path of lower level listening to keys and managing a submit state but figured I'd throw it out to the community to see if anyone knows of a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing with error-prone checks, you can also attach a submit event to the form. If the value is equal to the old value, don't submit the form by using `ev.preventDefault()`.

```
var oldvalue = "";
$("#my_form").submit(function(ev){
    var newvalue = $("#my_input", this).val();
    if(newvalue == oldvalue) ev.preventDefault(); //Same value, cancel submission
    else oldvalue = newvalue;
})
```

Comment: Very clean solution, I would suggest to control with some flags but yours is far way better

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the blur event http://api.jquery.com/blur/

This will fire when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Just an improvement to **Rob W**'s solution.

```
$('#my_form').submit((function () {
   //Enclose variables as to not pollute the global namespace
   var oldValue,
       input = $('#my_input');  //cache your input

   //Same concept as Rob W's solution
   return function (e) {
       var newValue = input.val();

       if(newValue === oldValue) {
          e.preventDefault();
       }

       oldValue = newValue;
   };
})());
```